# Codeigniter AMFPHP not working on live

Tags: apache, codeigniter, permissions, webserver, amfphp

I am developing a php flash based application and following [this tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/codeigniter203amfphp20/).

every thing is working fine on my `localhost` PC but, not on live server CentOS.

This tutorial guides to keep the amfphp library in `librarires` directory under application and create a controller '`gateway`' in `controllers/amf` and controllers as services into `controllers/amf/services`.

I have followed that properly and with that I am able to run it smoothly on localhost. Also, removing the sub directory `amf` is also working just fine

At live it gives

```
Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent:. level=error, code=NetConnection.Call.BadVersion
    at amfphpconnection_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

The connection from AS needs to be

```
http://domain.com/index.php/amf/gateway
```

I was trying different tricks to make it work and I found that if I kept the services from /controller/services/serices folder into application/libraries where amf itself resides and change the path to services in gateway then flash was able to reach the file when i changed the path in flash to

```
http://domain.com/application/libraries/Amfphp/
```

but, it still was not running properly until i removed the `extends CI_Controller` and `constructor function` or `get_instance()` from the service file. putting either raised the same error. this just runs the file but is useless for me because its not able to use CI framework then.

Using the controller path in the AS is what is required and **i think this is something related to file access permission** because its working fine on pc and not on linux.

I tried to look into **Apache error logs** too but no signs of any possible error out there.

Have looked loads of sites for help but no success as yet..

also posted bug at the [project site](https://code.google.com/p/codeigniter203amfphp20/issues/detail?id=4) itself but no updates are their as yet

any help would be appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem, and reading the AMFPHP website I saw on Windows there is no sensitive case files.

So, in CI they say, "name your class like 'myclass.php' and inside declare My_class extends CI_Controller". What I did in flash? I called "My_class" service. Since i was using windows to localhost, AMFPHP could find the file and work properly.

BUT not on linux. So, in flash, i called "this.connection.call("my_class", "mymethod", etc)" and all worked fine.

Hope this can be usefull someone. So, if you're deploying on Linux env, double check the case spell of your AMF calls and make sure you're calling **from flash the gateway.php** the perfect **name of your service file**, **NOT** the name of the class inside the file.

cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro :)

actually I found the error it was due to a library included that was printing HTML, as it was auto-loaded and flash just broke whenever it found data before the amfcall. removing that library from autoload fixed my issue..

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing this problem and I'm developing on OSX, I'm seeing the error

faultString => Testservice service not found

and this one...

*faultDetail => #0 /home/myserver.com/public_html/project/ci/application/libraries/Amfphp/Core/Common/ServiceRouter.php(100): Amfphp_Core_Common_ServiceRouter->getServiceObject('Testservice')
1 /home/myserver.com/public_html/project/ci/application/libraries/Amfphp/Core/Amf/Handler.php(107): Amfphp_Core_Common_ServiceRouter->executeServiceCall('Testservice', 'getAll', Array)
2 /home/myserver.com/public_html/project/ci/application/libraries/Amfphp/Core/Amf/Handler.php(138): Amfphp_Core_Amf_Handler->handleRequestMessage(Object(Amfphp_Core_Amf_Message), Object(Amfphp_Core_Common_ServiceRouter))
3 /home/myserver.com/public_html/project/ci/application/libraries/Amfphp/Core/Gateway.php(199): Amfphp_Core_Amf_Handler->handleDeserializedRequest(Object(Amfphp_Core_Amf_Packet), Object(Amfphp_Core_Common_ServiceRouter))
4 /home/myserver.com/public_html/project/ci/application/controllers/amf/gateway.php(39): Amfphp_Core_Gateway->service()
5 /home/myserver.com/public_html/project/ci/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(339): Gateway->index()
6 /home/myserver.com/public_html/project/ci/index.php(202): require_once('/home/ncubator/...')
7 {main}*

The files I'm using was from the google code page and I haven't changed the gateway file. I just changed the testservice.php contents to fit for my project. And my base URL is

http://myserver.com/project/ci/index.php/amf/gateway.

Could you provide a light on the solution you come up with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know about the Flash communication via `AMFPHP` Flash only accepts what it expects and if their is **anything beside that / before that** result in `Bad Connect` error at flash end... As I had already mentioned in comment to `ppalmeid's` answer my issue was due to the inclusion of a third party `library that was loading automatically` and it was **`printing some HTML characters in the output that was causing the Flash to blow`**.

Just check for any literally any **characters / warning / notices** and etc that are coming onto the screen.

Hope this helps anyone else facing the same issue.

Regards
Junaid